# Listen to both child_changed and child_added

Tags: javascript, firebase

My data is structured as follows :

[image]

When a particular user is logged to my app (I get his userId), I would like to listen to the addition of new "transactions" (I thought I should use "child_added") and to the modifications of "status" values ("child_changed" ?).

My code is the following :

```
var fb = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio-demo.com/users/" + userId + "/transactions");

fb.on('child_changed', function(data) {
    // do something
});

fb.on('child_added', function(data) {
    // do something
});
```

It is working perfectly with "child_changed", but as soon as I add the "child_added" part, the system seems to be stuck and slow.
Being new to firebase, I  am probably doing something very wrong... :)

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Is there a difference between the code for child added and child changed in your code or does it doesn't matter. Because i think when a child is added both events fire

Comment: The difference between `child_added` and `child_changed` is purely semantical. Technically they work the same. So likely the difference is in how you use these events or how you implement the handlers. Can you set up a *minimal* reproduction of the problem on a site like jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: @AndréKool I just checked it now and apparently when a new child is added, only the child_added is called, not the child_changed.